# php Curl open mp3 file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, curl

I am a web developer / music producer. and I'm working on my personal website.
I am using the `jplayer` jquery Plugin + `Php Curl` to retrieve the file.
However I'm getting a `301 error  permanently moved` ???? I don't understand why I'm getting this. I sent the content type header for audio/mepeg but no results .

HTML markup:

```
<?php
function beats(){
// <li><a href="hosts/beats/1.mp3" class="track track-default">1</a></li>
$beats = array("...."=>md5(1),"...."=>md5(2),"....."=>md5(3));
    foreach($beats as $key=>$value){
        echo "
        <li><a href=\"hosts/beats/beat.php?".md5('url')."=$value\" class=\"track\">$key</a></li>";
    }
}
?>
<ul class="playlist">
    <li><span>Select a track : </span></li>
    <? Beats(); ?>
</ul>
```

php curl file:

```
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST[md5('url')])){
    $beats = array(1=>md5(1),2=>md5(2),3=>md5(3));
    foreach($beats as $beatFile=>$url){
        if($_REQUEST[md5('url')] == $url){
            $BeatFile = $beatFile;  
        }
    }   
$url = $BeatFile.".mp3";
// Initializing curl
$ch = curl_init($url); 
// Configuring curl options
$options = array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('type=audio/mpeg') ,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $url
);
// Setting curl options
curl_setopt_array($ch,$options);
// Getting results
$beat =  curl_exec($ch);
echo $beat;
}else{
echo "No Permission";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

The server is redirecting you, but cURL's default behavior is to ignore redirects. Turn the option [`CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) on to follow the 301 redirect.

Also, you should remove your `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER`. There is no such header as `type=`, and even if there was, it would apply to the response and not the request.

Comment: can you post a code snip for me im unfamilair with what you are talking about now its just returning a empty page no mp3 file

Comment: @YoungnateDaGreat: add `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true` to your `$options` array, and remove the `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` entry from the same array. This should solve redirection errors.

Comment: Im getting an empty page do you have any idea why ? i mean its not an error page but,i need to know the the mp3 will be retrieved? i thought i would have to put content-type in there for the default video player to render ?